# Bootstrap responsive CSS image width skewed and distorted

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to create a website that uses the carousel component which takes up a large portion of the page. I am finding that when I resize the browser window and drag the viewport horizontally that the image width becomes skewed and distorted. I have set the following overall CSS styles for my carousel along with media queries for different widths.

Are there any amendments to my CSS rules or properties I can apply to `.carousel .item` and `.carousel img` to prevent the width of the image being distorted when the browser window is dragged horizontally? I was thinking `width:100%;` my possibly resolve this issue?

Here is an image of the skewing occuring when resizing the browser horizontally:
[image]

Here is the website: http://www.the-session.co.uk/jen/

Here is the CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 900px;
}
.carousel img {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {

  .carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
  }
  .carousel img {
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .carousel .item {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel img {
    height: 300px;
  } 
}
```

Comment: @user15542624  Check the solution

Answer (score 6):

The problem lies in the fact that you are defining a specific height and/or width (depending on your layout) which is causing the issue. If your design allows for it, change the *"height:900px"* from *.carousel img* to *"height:auto"* in both your @media files so that your image is not being distorted.

If however the desired outcome is to actually have the carousel image expand to fill the whole viewport another solution will be necessary, likely requiring to change the images to background images to fill an absolutely positioned div.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with trying to scale images that way is that you are not preserving the initial aspect ratio of the image.

Instead, try `background-size: contain`. This instructs the browser to scale the image, proportionately, such that the image will fill the container along the longer axis.

Comment: That obviously only applies to background-images.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the wrong values for height in the media queries . Since your img height in main css is set to  `height:900px;` You need to do the following :

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {

 .carousel .item {
     height: 750px;
 }
  .carousel img {
    width: auto;
    height: 75 0px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

   .carousel .item {
     height: 600px;
    }
   .carousel img {
     height: 600px;
 } 
}
```