# Bootstrap website banner distortion on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using a bootstrap website creator, jetstrap, I created a simple website with a banner image stretching the size of the window. The problem is the image stretched has a logo on it, and on resizing the window the image gets distorted and streched.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042986/bootstrap-responsive-css-image-width-skewed-and-distorted) thread which describes the problem well, and i attempted to change the css with background-size: contain which did not seem to work.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thank you!

example here: http://www.filedropper.com/jetstrapexample2

Comment: Hi! Could you post your relevant HTML and CSS? Better yet, show a mockup in JSFiddle.net? Sometimes the problem is actually outside what you described and seeing the whole picture can help.  For example, I thinking the 'banner image' might incorporate the logo as well?  But I'm not sure and seeing how you're doing it will help.  Thanks!

Comment: thank you!  I'll throw a fiddle together in a sec

Comment: it does not render correctly in js fiddle, here is a example zip http://www.filedropper.com/jetstrapexample2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander De Sousa pretty much hits on it but here's some specific code to your example:

In your file, you have an `<img>` tag that you're absolutely positioning with `width:100%` to stretch the size of the screen.  This is the code bits:

```
<img class="jetstrap-selected jetstrap-highlighted" id="backimage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.jetstrap.com/Nd7Z0DbqQ4eNN2cV05DI_background.png">
```

It is inside a div container called with a class name "carousel".

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-pause="remove">...</div>
```

The CSS controlling this element is at the bottom the HTML page you gave as download above.  The relavant CSS that's affecting this element is:

```
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;  /* THIS IS THE PROBLEM */
  background-size: contain;
}
```

As you can see in the CSS above, it's setting a very specific height value.  This is throwing the Aspect Ratio of your Background image off.  Meaning, when using `min-width:100%;`, the actual width, in terms of pixels, is variable to the screen size.

If the screen is 1000px wide, your image is 1000px wide.  If you resize it down to 875px, your image is 875px.

At this time, your height is always remaining at 500px.  So your background picture, which uses patterned background with a fairly large square "logo" image, is actually being distorted by CSS request.

Because at one moment it's `1000px / 500px` and at another it's `875px / 500px`.

Of course, there's media queries involved too.  At different screen sizes, the height value is set to a specific value.

What I think you're trying to go for is to have a tiled background image with a logo that can adjust it's size/positioning responsively (ie. to the screen size).

You'll want to consider doing something more like this:

```
<div id="#background">
    <img src="myLogo.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

This container will function as you background.  I would place this before the end of your `<div id="myCarousel">...</div>` element.

From there, you position that container and fill it with a repeating background (or you could add another responsive image to scale it):

```
#background{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;  /* You can set a specific height here, so it covers your content */
  background: url(myBackground.png) repeat 50% 50%; /* if you don't want your background to distort, use a tiled background */
}
```

With the "logo", you absolutely position that inside your background container as needed.

```
#background img{
  position:absolute;
  top:10em;
  right:20%;
  width:200px; /* Or use a % to scale the logo fluidly */
}
```

With media queries, you can adjust the position of the logo as needed for the screen size.

This technique keeps your background image consistent, so it doesn't shrink/expand the gradient.  Instead, the background will crop as the screen size changes.  If you prefer a scaling background you can simply add another img inside the background container and appropriately label them with a CSS class or ID and apply styles.

```
<div id="#background">
    <img id="myBgLogo" src="myLogo.png" alt="" />
    <img id="myBgFill" src="myBackground.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Then just target the images specifically and layer them, giving the background a 100% width and height.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
.background img {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
```

To keep images in proportion you can set any width you like but make sure you have specified height as auto.

*It could be worth sharing a link to the site you're working on*

Comment: Alexander pretty much got it but I don't think that's going to help you in your design case.  I DLed your files but I'm out of time for now to try something and write it up.  I'll see if I can get an example setup later tonight.

Comment: Gotcha.  This bootstrap is maddening.  Starting from scratch would have been better. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defining a specific height to the image that is larger than the aspect ratio of  the image. You will either need to remove the height definition or change the image to a background of an absolutely positioned div to have it expand beyond the viewport.